# forge.prefs.set() not work with iPhone simulator

Tags: trigger.io

I'm developing application with trigger.io and i'm trying to save some data to the device

this is my code for example

```
 forge.prefs.set('tokens', 'Some Data');
```

and when getting it with

```
 var tokens=forge.prefs.get('tokens');
 forge.logging.log(tokens);
```

i'm getting

```
  [INFO] [FORGE] undefined
```

the prefs module is enabled and i tried to clear it first with this code

```
forge.prefs.clear('tokens');
```

my Iphone simulator is 6.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `forge` functions is normally asynchronous, to get a pref you need do do something like

```
 forge.prefs.get("tokens", function (tokens) {
     forge.logging.log(tokens);
 });
```

http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/features/api.html has more details.

Comment: Thanks for your reply i need to assign prefs value to variable to use it somewhere else ho can i do that ?

Comment: Yeah....how are we going to assign the value in a variable and use it in our scripts? because we have many prefs and will pass prefs values in a function as a parameter